# Swashbuckle wraps number examples with double quotes from VS XML comments

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a class representing a body for an endpoint, in that class is an `Amount` property, it looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// The transaction amount; it must be greater than 0
/// </summary>
/// <example>1.23</example>
[JsonProperty("Amount")]
[Required]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

The problem I'm having is that when Swashbuckle generates the JSON for this Request body example, it ends up wrapping the `Amount` value with double quotes like this:

```
{
  "Amount": "1.23"
}
```

I want it to look like a number, like this:

```
{
  "Amount": 1.23
}
```

If I give no XML example tag, the Request Body example generated in the SwaggerUI is just `0.0` with no double quotes, like this:

```
{
  "Amount": 0.0
}
```

The portion of the XML comments that is generated from this example doesn't have quotes:

```
<member name="P:MyAPI.Models.SaleRequest.Amount">
    <summary>
    The transaction amount; it must be greater than 0
    </summary>
    <example>1.23</example>
</member>
```

But the JSON generated from Swashbuckle does:

```
"SaleRequest": {
    "required": [
        "Amount"
    ],
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Amount": {
            "format": "decimal",
            "description": "The transaction amount; it must be greater than 0",
            "type": "number",
            "example": "1.23"
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can tell Swashbuckle not to wrap this XML example tag for a number property with double quotes? I've been searching for a while and can't find anything. I've tried `c.MapType<decimal>(() => new Schema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal" });` from another post when configuring swagger but that didn't change anything. I didn't see any attributes I could apply to the property in the source code either. I'm using Swashbuckle 4.0.1

Comment: You might want to file a bug report in the Swashbuckle repository.

Comment: @Helen Ah okay, I wasn't quite sure if this was a bug or if I was missing some sort of configuration. I can do that.

Comment: Could be useful to post back here your bug link so you get more support ;)